# Does Amos intentionally call Konecheck "Tiny" in order to force him to attack the others?

Tags: the-expanse-2015

In The Expanse (TV), S5, Amos and Peaches are trying to escape from The Pit and Konecheck ("Tiny") is recruited to help. Amos must know that he is dangerous but he won't stop calling him "Tiny", which obviously makes him angry. I haven't read that far in the books and I'm not even sure if Tiny is part of them, but: did Amos know that he would eventually force Konecheck to attack them, with the hopes of killing him at the prison without having to keep him around and potentially dangerous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potential spoilers for Nemesis Games

Konecheck/Tiny is in the books.

There's no indication that calling him Tiny was a strategy on Amos's part, but he did realize that they would eventually most likely have a confrontation.

> Amos considered Konecheck out of the corner of his eyes. Still too early
> to be sure, but maybe sixty-forty that one of them was going to have to kill
> the other. Not now, but before it was over. He could hope for the forty.

The first time Amos calls him "Tiny" we don't get any thoughts from Amos saying it was to purposefully make him angry. It seems to just be a nickname similar to the other nicknames Amos gives people

> “Hey, Tiny,” he called. “You come down here a minute?”
>
> After a short silence, Konecheck’s growl came down. “What’d you call
> me?”
>
> “Tiny. Just come take a look at this. See if we’ve got something.”

In fact, it seems like Amos is doing a lot to keep the peace with Konecheck and the guards, at least until they've escaped the Pit.

I don't know how the plan worked in the show, but in the books, they climb an elevator shaft to escape. The guards use their guns to punch holes in the metal wall of the shaft and Konecheck uses his enhanced strength to reach into the hole and rip the metal further to make hand holds. Because of this, he and guard are in front climbing the shaft.

> Two  more  gunshots  from  the  shaft,  a  murmur  of  voices,  and
> then  a scream. Amos was on his feet almost before Sullivan’s body
> fell past. He landed in the muck at the bottom of the shaft. Rona
> cried out wordlessly, dropping  down  to  him  while  Morris  turned
> his  flashlight  up  the  ladder. Konecheck’s feet were two pale dots,
> his face a shadow above them.
>
> “He slipped,” Konecheck called.
>
> “The hell he did!” Rona shouted. Her gun was in her hand, and she was going
> for the ladder. Amos jumped down and got in her way, his hands spread
> wide. “Hey, hey, hey. Don’t get crazy here. We need that guy.”
>
> “Coming up on level four,” Konecheck said. “Starting to see light up top.
> Hear the wind. Almost there.”
>
> Sullivan lay in the muck, his leg folded unnaturally under him, and limp as a rag. He still had the gun in his fist. A yellow indicator on the side said he was out of ammunition. Sullivan had lived just long enough to stop being useful, then Konecheck had murdered him.
>
> Asshole couldn’t have waited until they were all the way up.
>
> “He  slipped,”  Amos  said.  “Shit  like  that happens.  Don’t  do  anything stupid.”

Everyone knows Konecheck murdered the guard, but Amos tries to convince the guard to let it go so that they could all escape. If he's going to that kind of effort to play peacemaker, it doesn't make sense that he would intentionally antagonize Konecheck with a nickname.